# Java library for SSL/TLS communication

Tags: java, ssl, protocols

Is there a way to establish the SSL/TLS communication between a Java implementation and some other application? I want my implementation to craft and send the standard protocol communication messages (e.g. ClientHello etc.) and establish a secure connection to the external app by myself.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I analysed the client-server traffic via Wireshark and used the library HttpClient in my implementation for HTTP messaging... However, both of them do not offer me the possibility to act on the protocol message level.

Comment: Java allows you to communicate over SSL/TLS in a way that allows you to focus on what you communicate and not on the protocol. If you want to implement the protocol directly, you are welcome to do so, wrapping your code around a simple TCP connection. But what is your question, exactly?

Comment: I want to test whether I can exploit a protocol vulnerability (e.g. Heartbleed) while communicating with a program. In this case, I have to set the value of a parameter of the message on protocol level manually (e.g. increase the value of allowed payload length etc.) in Java.